# OVR Interaction: Two grab free transformer

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

Anyone know how to use Two grab free transformers just to perform two hand grab using the Oculus package

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, There is a Grabble component which take Two Grab Transform ref, add the
   two grab free transformer component and give to ref to it and change
   constraints value min and max whatever you want.
2. Untick the reset grab on grabs update in Hand Grab Interactable component.